# C++ Two Dimensional Array Value Increase

Tags: c++, arrays

I am looking to finish up this program for class. I'm lost when it comes to arrays and I've read all the course work, the book, etc. The question is how do you increase a two dimensional array element at the position?

```
    int main()
{
 int quantity, warehouse, product;
int inventory[4][5] = {
{900,400,250,95,153},
{52, 95, 625, 44, 250},
{100,720,301,50,878},
{325,650,57,445,584},
};
cout << "Enter the warehouse number between 1 and 4: " << endl;
cin >> warehouse;
cout << "Enter the product location between 1 and 5: " << endl;
cin >> product;
cout << "Enter the quantity delivered: " << endl;
cin >> quantity;        

 /* First the addition */
for(warehouse = 0; warehouse < 4; warehouse++)
for(product = 0; product < 5; product++)
inventory[warehouse][product] + quantity;

cout << "The amount of units in warehouse " << warehouse << " is \n\n";


/* Then print the results */
for(warehouse = 0; warehouse < 4; warehouse++ ) {
                for( product = 0; product < 5; product++ )
                    cout << "\t" <<  inventory[warehouse][product];
                cout << endl;   /* at end of each warehouse */
}
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(warehouse = 0; warehouse < 4; warehouse++)
for(product = 0; product < 5; product++)
inventory[warehouse][product] + quantity;
```

You don't need to iterate over the array like this at all. Get rid of those `for` loops. The `warehouse` and `product` values were input by the user. You simply need to access the element the corresponding element and add to it:

```
inventory[warehouse][product] += quantity;
```

Notice the use of `+=`. This actually modifies the value in the array, rather than just taking the value and adding `quantity` to it.

Next, it looks like you only want to print out the inventory for the warehouse corresponding to `warehouse`. To do this, you should not be iterating over all of the warehouses, and only iterating over the products:

```
for( product = 0; product < 5; product++ ) {
  cout << "\t" <<  inventory[warehouse][product];
}
```

The lesson here is that you only need to iterate over some elements if you need to do something to each of them. In the first case, you only needed to add a value to one element, so no iteration is necessary. In the second case, you needed to print out a row of elements, so you had to iterate over just that row.

Comment: Thanks guys. That made perfect sense and my program works perfectly. I wonder why the reading a book on this is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines after the

```
/* First the Addition */
```

are uneccessary, it seems like you tried to loop through the array to get to the index you wanted to change. That was unnecessary.

```
inventory[warehouse][product] += quantity;
```

is all you need to have the program work correctly. It will add the quantity the user specified to the index the user specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
inventory[warehouse][product] + quantity;
```

should be

```
inventory[warehouse][product] += quantity;
//                            ^^
```

The `+` only returns the addition, it doesn't modify any of its operands. `a += b` is synonymous to `a = a + b`.

There is also no need for a for loop here. The values are already given.